Motion polynomials
Motion polynomials are rational rigid body motions in the Euclidean 3-space. Their support is a rational curve that belong to the study quadric $\mathcal{S}^7\subset\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^7$
$$\mathcal{S}^7:=\{(x_0:x_1:x_2:x_3:y_0:y_1:y_2:y_3)\in\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^7:x_0y_0+x_1y_1+x_2y_2+x_3y_3=0\}.$$
Motion polynomials are related to applications to robot path-planning and computer animation. Their factorization allows to decompose the system into simpler paths. So it becomes a very interesting algebraic problem, nevertheless, rigid transformation are naturally studied in quaternion algebra.
I hardly find references of motion polynomials, does anyone know a good way to get into them? Also, as a mathematician, I have difficulties at understanding their concrete application. Is there anything I should consult?
Thank you for any help.
